# Spacing in div tag in table

Tags: html, css

```
<tr >
<td><div id="wrap"><c:out value = "User ID"/>
<c:out value = "User Name"/>
<c:out value = "User Answer"/></div></td>
</tr>


#wrap{
width: 90%;
max-width: 1200 px;
margin: 20px auto;
}
```

O/P: User ID User Name User Answer

However , i want spacing between UserID , User Name and User Answer

what can i do? I am new to HTML/CSS

Comment: What kind of spacing are you looking for? Left/right?

Comment: what is the `<c:out>` tag?

Comment: &nbsp; and yes what is <c: out> tag ?

Comment: @celeriko <c:out> is a jstl tag that display a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, although I haven't tested this out

```
.title{
   margin-right: 20px;
   float: left;
}

<tr >
    <td>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="title"><c:out value = "User ID"/></div>
        <div class="title"><c:out value = "User Name"/></div>
        <div class="title"><c:out value = "User Answer"/></div>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT:**

This works. Look at  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rdVt/)
If you want to increase the space, then just change the value of "margin-right" to a bigger value.